# Corona SDK Android Copy textfield bug

Tags: android, copy, coronasdk, textfield

I have noticed a strange behaviour when I tried to copy my text that I had typed into my textfield. The application seems to decrease its size and shows things from off-screen.
Can I do something to prevent from this? :)

[image]

[image]